# How to check whole object from inside the setter

Tags: java, oop

I got an assignment in Java class to write a class that represents a Date, with getters\settes.
the constructor gets 3 ints (d,m,y) and checks if the date is legal.
the problem is that in the setter setDay(int day), I can only think of one way to check if the day is legal -

```
void setDay(int dayToSet)
{
    if(dayToSet>=1 && dayToSet <=31)
    {
    int_day = dayToSet;
    }
}
```

It is a problem, if the object is a date like 29/2/2020, I can set it to be 30-31/2/2020 . 
what is the best solution for this?
I do have a copy constructor but I can't see how it will help me, I pass a single int and don't know how to check if the date represented by the object should be changed or not (the assignment declares that if the setDaty(int day) is illegal I should not change the date).
also, I do have private methods that check if every component of the object is legal , for instance:

```
private boolean longMonth(int day, int month, int year)
{
    if(day>=ONE && day <=THIRTY_ONE && year>NINE_HUNDRED && month == ONE && year <=NINETHOUSAND ||
            day>=ONE && day <=THIRTY_ONE && year>NINE_HUNDRED && month == THREE && year <=NINETHOUSAND|| 
            day>=ONE && day <=THIRTY_ONE && year>NINE_HUNDRED && month == FIVE && year <=NINETHOUSAND|| 
            day>=ONE && day <=THIRTY_ONE && year>NINE_HUNDRED && month == SEVEN && year <=NINETHOUSAND||
            day>=ONE && day <=THIRTY_ONE && year>NINE_HUNDRED && month == EIGHT && year <=NINETHOUSAND||
            day>=ONE && day <=THIRTY_ONE && year>NINE_HUNDRED && month == TEN && year <=NINETHOUSAND||
            day>=ONE && day <=THIRTY_ONE && year>NINE_HUNDRED && month == TWELVE && year <=NINETHOUSAND)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But i need to pass a valid input (3 ints) while i only have one.

Comment: Setup some kind of if/else/switch based on the provided month and then you can limit what days are available for each month.

Comment: You probably need to check how many days there are in the current month for that year. Dunno if you are supposed to consider leap years.

Comment: just use `java.util.Date` with your desired `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: I don't think this is a good task for beginners... Nevermind, you could make the decision depending on the month and put several hard coded borders ;-)

Comment: Do you also have to deal with Leap years? February 29th is not valid every year

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you have one method that checks the validity of the date as a whole. It will be called from all three setter methods. It should call the three getter methods, and then check the validity of the date.

**EDIT:**

to explain why one validity method needs to be called from all setter methods, imagine the following scenario:

```
MyDate myDate = new MyDate();
myDate.setYear(2019);
myDate.setMonth(1);
myDate.setDay(31);
// the date is 31st, Jan, 2019 - quite valid
myDate.setMonth(2);
// oh no! setting the month has caused the date to become invalid!
```

**2nd EDIT:**

I understand it is tricky to figure out how to trigger validation of a whole date from setter of one property. Here is my siggestion:

first, the standalone validation method signature is

```
private boolean isValidDate(int year, int month, int day)
```

I will let you develop the method body. It has all the information it needs to perform its task.

calling the method from one setter requires the setter to use getters of the other  properties, while passing its argument to the validation method:

```
void setDay(int dayToSet) {
    if (isValidDate(getYear(), getMonth(), dayToSet)) {
        // safe to modify instance variable 
        this.int_day = dayToSet;
    } else {
        // new value causes an invalid date, maybe throw exception? 
        // IllegalArgumentException seems appropriate (its from java.lang i.e. does not require import)
```

this ensures that the validation method is triggered after every change to any property and that it correctly validates the about-to-be-modified state of the object *before* it is actually modified.

Comment: Thank you!
int the year/ month setter it is pretty simple 
if(month >= 1 && month <=12)
if(year>= 1000 && year <=9999)
the day setter is the problem, and every method that check if the date is valid 
requires 3 ints (d/m/y) but in the setter i only pass one (day).

Comment: @WhiteLister you should not be testing for validity in the setters. You need a separate method `public boolean validate()` and that method will get the 3 numbers and validate that the date is correct

Comment: @WhiteLister, see edited answer for explanation why you need to validate the date from each setter

Comment: Any idea how to implement it?
if it validates a date object - it needs 3 ints, while every setter only sets one int.
so how to validate the whole object if I'm missing data?

Comment: I will try it - it seems to be a good answer to the problem.
anyway, I started to make a validator for the global variables, so if someone tries to set a value, a method inside the setter will check the global ints that represent the (d/m/y), something like -
 void setDay(int dayToSet)
 {
  if(dayToSet>=ONE && dayToSet <=THIRTY_ONE && this.int_month 
                    == 1,3,5,7,8,10,12)
  {
  int_day = dayToSet;
  }
 } 
No else needed because the assiggment states if set value is not valid - do not change the object.
hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the code and added the setters

- First of all you make the no argument constructor private, this way you are sure your `MyDate` object can only be instantiated using the constructor that take the 3 ints (day, month, year)

Now **we are sure that the instance always has the 3 values.** There will be no case where the date only has the day and not the month for example.

- Create a validation method, and that validation method throws an exception when you try to set an invalid value (`validate` in the example below)
- Finally, in the constructor and in each setter, call the validation method before you set the value. 
  If the value is valid, it will be set, if it is invalid an exception will be throw, and the object will not be modified.

```
public class MyDate {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;


    private MyDate() {
        // make it private to make sure nobody uses this one
    }

    public MyDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;

        validate(day, month, year);
    }

    public void validate(int day, int month, int year) {
        if(!isValid(day, month, year)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid date");
        }
    }

    public boolean isValid(int day, int month, int year) {
        // Add you validation logic here 
        return month >=1  && month <= 12;
    }


    public void setDay(int day) {
        validate(day, this.month, this.year);
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        validate(this.day, month, this.year);
        this.month = month;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        validate(this.day, this.month, year);
        this.year = year;
    }

    // GETTERS
}
```

Then this will not compile because this constructor is private:

```
MyDate date = new MyDate();
```

This will be ok

```
MyDate date = new MyDate(1, 1, 2000);
date.setMonth(6);
```

This will throw an exception

```
MyDate date = new MyDate(1, 13, 2000);
```

And this will also throw an exception

```
MyDate date = new MyDate(1, 1, 2000);
date.setMonth(13);
```

Comment: it is quite acceptable that setter method do input validation. checking for validity should be the responsibility of the class. it is bad practice to rely on the caller to initiate input validation. what if the caller forgets to do that?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher In this case the setter alone can't do the validation, because you don't know how many days will be in the month until you know the month. So you need all the data to validate. If we wanted this kind of validation, I would go for a Builder pattern and do the input validation in the build()

Comment: If it were bad form to put validation in setters, there wouldn't be much point in having setters in the first place - public fields would do. I do agree there's shouldn't be setters in this class to begin with, but it sounds like they were part of the assignment.

Comment: @Bentaye, the setter alone can do the validation. setters can inspect the whole state of the object and perform validation. however, in this case, it is better to delegate the validation to a separate method since all setters basically need to do the same validation

Comment: Well, I do have validation inside the constructor, and also in the month and year setters I made a few if's and that's it, but the day setter as I stated is more complicated, I need to check the whole object to know if the input is valid.

Comment: @WhiteLister are these setters a requirement? if no, then don't add setters they are not required.

Comment: unfortunately yes, they are a requirement :(

Comment: @WhiteLister the problem is that a setter has a void return type. What is supposed to happen if you try to set the day to 32? It just does not set it?

Comment: @WhiteLister I updated the code with a solution using setters, have a look

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to pass in the month and year - see this example using Date and SimpleDateFormat.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // format the way you want
        sdf.setLenient(false);

        try {
          Date date = sdf.parse("03-34-1996"); // if we change this to a valid date, it's accepted
          System.out.println("valid");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // we are here because the date was not valid
            System.out.println("not valid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has to create a custom class that represents a date, that means OP is not allowed to use the (outdated) class `java.util.Date`, most likely...

Comment: Thank you! 
unfortunately, I can't use any imports in my task :(

Comment: Ah, this is useless then. I guess I would look at how that class achieves it and work off of that...

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to use Java's [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). You can initialize your date by

```
LocalDate.of(day, month, year)
```

This also checks for leap years. If the day is not valid, an exception is thrown.

Comment: OP has to create a custom class that represents a date, that means OP is not allowed to use the modern class `java.time.LocalDate`, most likely...